# Cannot delete files in Visual Studio 17 solution explorer (no error message)

Tags: visual-studio

I have been having this issue with Visual Studio 2017 (using version 15.8.6, the latest version at this time) where it will not allow me to delete files in the solution explorer. I have to delete the file outside of VS and then remove it from the project file manually, which is a lot of hassle.

Unlike the other stack overflow questions I have seen about this issue, in my case I do not get an error message. It brings up the usual confirmation box, and when I click 'OK' the confirmation box disappears but the file remains.

It might be worth noting that I am having this issue on my work laptop. Also, on the rare occasion it seems to succeed (after updating it deleted one file successfully then stopped working again).

Edit: This doesn't seem to be an issue anymore. Maybe they patched it?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same/similar issue (VS '17 15.9.4)
If I open the same solution with VS '15 then I will be able to delete, copy, move files around in the tree.

In my case, though, these actions never succeed. Even the right click menu of the files is different.